# unable to access apache web server on vmware guest machine

Tags: apache-http-server, vmware

I have Apache Web server installed on VMWare guest machine, it has bridged LAN connection with static IP Address 192.168.1.253 while the host machine has IP Address 192.168.1.2

My Host is behind router, the router has local IP Address 192.168.1.1 and also has Public IP 101.254.x.x NATed/Port Forwarded to the guest machine

Now the problem is I'm able to access my site hosted on the guest machine from the host but not from the internet even though it should also be accessible from the internet, I have ftp and SSH service running on my guest machine and having no problem accessing the apps/services from the Internet.

I would appreciate any help or solutions related to the problem mentioned above, thanks

Comment: Have you forwarded port 80 on your router to 192.168.1.2? And are you certain there are no firewalls (router, host, or guest) blocking the connection?

Comment: @Anaksunaman yes I have dst-nat rule to 192.168.1.2:8000 for apache service and its working, sudo ufw status return 'inactive'

Comment: @Run5k Okay, thank you.

Comment: @Anaksunaman dst-nat from 101.254.x.x:80 to 192.168.1.2:80 also accessible from the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling second port in apache2 ports.conf is the solution for me
in my case i have added second port in ports.conf
Listen 80 and
Listen 81 
and now all services (except port 80) are accessible from the internet